# Rendering issue regarding imagery versus functionality

Tags: c++, render, sdl-2

As I understand rendering textures in SDL2, everything is waiting behind the scenes and a texture appears after using the SDL_RenderPresent() function and vanishes with SDL_RenderClear(), which you use before advancing to the next frame.

I understand that as far as it goes for imagery, but what about functionality? I have two button textures linked to mouse events that I want to see and use at different times in different places. I've got them rendering during different enum states and each button does indeed appear and disappear on cue when the states change.

However, since both button textures are always "there" even while not being rendered, I can still mouse click on the invisible button that isn't being rendered at any given time. This doesn't seem to be an issue for mouse motion events, just mouse button events. How do I make a texture inactive as well as invisible when it's not being rendered?

Comment: `SDL_RenderClear` only takes effect at the next `SDL_RenderPresent`, just like `SDL_RenderCopy` etc, otherwise you'd see flickering. *"both button textures are always "there" even while not being rendered, I can still mouse click on the invisible button ... an issue for ... mouse button events"* The question doesn't make sense. SDL itself doesn't provide any "which texture is clicked" events, it just gives you the click coordinates, at which point you're free to check which buttons are visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this one with some tinkering and a more experienced programmer named mbozzi's help to clue me in the right direction as to what was going on. The underlying issue was due to my completely decoupling the GUI logic and GUI rendering. Which is what we are always told to do: decouple everything, right? But I needed to couple the logic and rendering that I want to occur at the same time and place.

My event poll>>mouse input>>image rendering code was one giant loop. However, when I split that giant loop into separate mini event poll>>mouse input>>image rendering loops that each runs independently (but not concurrently, I just put them in their own different enum game states), that clears up the issue. So, if anyone has a similar problem with clicking invisible buttons, hopefully this will help.